# Is there a documentation standard for custom XML style attributes in Android?

Tags: java, android, xml, javadoc, documentation-generation

I am able to document pretty much everything in in my Android projects and generate nice-looking API references for them.

The only exception to this are the XML files, and especially the attribute files that contain the styleable attributes.

For example, a portion of *res/values/attrs.xml*:

```
<resources>
    <declare-styleable name="TimelineView">
        <attr name="drawCollapsed" format="boolean" />
    </declare-styleable>
</resources>
```

I noticed that in the Android source, [standard attributes documentation is generated for R](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html).

My generated documentation, obviously, includes some generic text for my attribute type (boolean, in this case):

[image: auto-documented property]

Is there an official specification for this type of documentation or a way to document attributes originating in XML such that the description appears in the auto-generated JavaDoc?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I am not sure that this is an official standard, but I stumbled across it when writing my question. I decided to post the question and answer it anyway, for the sake of other who might encounter this issue.

I was able to generate attribute documentation by adding an XML comment above the attribute, which seems quite apparent now that I have seen it.

I initially tried it without rebuilding my project, which lead to the original lack of documentation. Once I rebuilt the module and generated the JavaDoc, I got the desired result.

The steps to follow are:

1. Place a comment above desired attribute(s).

   ```xml
   <resources>
       <declare-styleable name="TimelineView">
           <!-- Initially draw collapsed until adapters have been set. -->
           <attr name="drawCollapsed" format="boolean" />
       </declare-styleable>

   </resources>
   ```
2. Rebuild the relevant module/project.
3. Generate the JavaDoc. Using Android Studio (currently 0.5.8).
   There is currently a [small issue](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=63249) with the automatic generation, I am using the workaround introduced in the first linked post.
   The generated documentation should contain your comments.
   [image: desired documentation]

If anyone knows of any official sources for this or an official method, please don't hesitate to share them.

**Update:**
It seems this is indeed the way it is done in the [Android source files](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/res/res/values/attrs.xml), including some JavaDoc directives, HTML and child annotation in the comments, for example:

```
<!-- Alignment constants. -->
<attr name="alignmentMode">
    <!-- Align the bounds of the children.
    See {@link android.widget.GridLayout#ALIGN_BOUNDS}. -->
    <enum name="alignBounds" value="0" />
    <!-- Align the margins of the children.
    See {@link android.widget.GridLayout#ALIGN_MARGINS}. -->
    <enum name="alignMargins" value="1" />
</attr>
```

Comment: Are your comments on the XML resources reaching the output of the javadoc or R.java? I am creating the javadoc via gradle as I describe in a similar question, but the default documentation is added for my XML resources: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35430792/adding-documentation-for-generated-r-java-files-in-android-studio

Comment: @Petrakeas, I haven't done Android development recently, so I opened my original project and updated it to work with the latest version of AndroidStudio (v2.0-beta5). It seems that the data from the XML does not reach `R.java` and hence does not find its way into the JavaDoc, so it does not work as it used to. I am getting lots of `@attr is an unknown tag` warnings in the process, but I don't have time to dive any deeper into it. I did not try to generate the JavaDoc from gradle and I haven't tried DocLava, but the issue may related to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/33246400/268093).

Comment: I looked at e.g. [TextView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html) and in the source (at the class doc) there is an entry for each XML attribute:`@attr ref android.R.styleable#TextView_text`. I guess this is how it gets to the class' javadoc, in the section "XML attributes". However, when I add the corresponding `@attr ref mypackage.R.styleable#MyClass_myattr` (and XML comments at myatrr) but the generated documenttion just contains the standard text. Further there are warnings on the console: "warning - @attr is an unknown tag." but actually for Android classes!