# Adding documentation for generated R.java files in Android Studio

Tags: gradle, javadoc, r.java-file

In my Gradle script, I have created a Javadoc task that generates documentation for my java files and for the auto-generated R.java, so that it creates links for my XML resources. I am using Doclava and even the `@attr`works [as expected](https://code.google.com/archive/p/doclava/wikis/JavadocTags.wiki) when referencing XML resources.

However, when I add comments in my original XML files in order to document them, they are lost in the process of generating the R.java file and they are replaced by the default documentation.

Is there a way to document my XML resources and make the documentation appear in the resulting javadoc?